# Ruby gem conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to update a specific Slack-Client gem from version 1 to version 2.

The problem that the version 2 uses another gem called Faraday with version 2 and I have in Gemfile another gem called Kit that uses Faraday version 1.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    faraday (= 1.10.2)

  In Gemfile:
    oktakit was resolved to 0.3.3, which depends on
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2)

    slack-ruby-client (= 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      faraday (>= 2.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

1. I would like to know if there is a way to update Slack-Client to version 2 without create a new conflict
2. I've tried different approaches, but all of them create the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot require the same gem multiple times in different versions in your application at the same time. In your case, this means that you cannot update `slack-ruby-client` to a version that requires `faraday >= 2.0` while keeping the `oktakit` gem at a version that requires `faraday < 2`.

Because there is no never version of `oktakit` available, you are stuck and have to wait for `oktakit` to be updated.

What you could try, is forking those gems and try if one of them would work with the `faraday` version required by the other. Or you investigate if you can replace `oktakit` with any other [Okta related gem](https://rubygems.org/search?query=okta) that supports your use case.